# Bash script to extract values from HTML

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, curl, html

I am trying to extract counter values from a HA7NET 1wire device server, but I am not so used with sed or awk or bash scripts so I am running in to problems.

This script gives me an array with the counter ID's:

```
#!/bin/sh
Counters=$(curl -q "http://192.168.70.21/1Wire/Search.html?FamilyCode=1D" 2>/dev/null | sed --silent -e 's/.*<INPUT.*NAME="Address_\(.*\)".*VALUE="\(.*\)".*./\2/p')

# iterating by for to see the array.
for x in $Counters; do echo $x; done;
```

The results lists the devices and looks like this:

```
    D90000000C8A9A1D
    C00000000C8C9D1D
    2D0000000EE97D1D
```

Now I want to use the array for an other curl request to get the actual reading for the counter?
The url to get the reading from both counters (every device has 2 counters A,B) it could bee extended to read all the devices at once and looks like this:

```
curl -q "http://192.168.70.21/1Wire/ReadCounter.html?Address_Channel_Array={D90000000C8A9A1D,A},{D90000000C8A9A1D,B},{C00000000C8C9D1D,A},{C00000000C8C9D1D,B},2D0000000EE97D1D,A},{2D0000000EE97D1D,B}"
```

And the resulting html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/1WireReply.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Read Counter Reply</title><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" --><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@import url("/eds.css");
-->
</style>
<!-- InstanceParam name="pagePreprocessor" type="text" value="preProcessReadCounter" --><!-- InstanceParam name="functionname" type="text" value="Read Counter" --><!-- InstanceParam name="nextpage" type="text" value="PgReadCounterResult" --><!-- InstanceParam name="enctype" type="text" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --><!-- InstanceParam name="name" type="text" value="Read Counter Result" -->
</head><body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
<tr>
<td class="title" colspan="2"><h1>&nbsp;</h1><h1 class="title">Embedded Data Systems</h1><a class="title" href="http://www.embeddeddatasystems.com">http://www.embeddeddatasystems.com</a></td></tr><tr class="spacer">
<td><H2 class="spacer">Read Counter Reply</h2></td><td><p class="spacer">HA7Net: 1.0.0.22</p></td></tr><tr>
<td colspan="2"><FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="/Forms/ReadCounterResult_1" name="Read Counter Result"><table name="Exceptions" ID="Exceptions">
<tr>
<td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Exception_Code_0" ID="Exception_Code_0" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0" Size="5" disabled></td><td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Exception_String_0" ID="Exception_String_0" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="None" Size="5" disabled></td></tr></table><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="WorkArea" -->
<table name="Counter" id="Counter">
<tr><td colspan=1>Address</td><td colspan=1>Count</td><td colspan=1>Status</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_0" ID="Address_0" TYPE="text" VALUE="D90000000C8A9A1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_0" ID="Count_0" TYPE="text" VALUE="240155653"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_0" ID="Device_Exception_0" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_0" ID="Device_Exception_Code_0" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_1" ID="Address_1" TYPE="text" VALUE="D90000000C8A9A1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_1" ID="Count_1" TYPE="text" VALUE="48719610"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_1" ID="Device_Exception_1" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_1" ID="Device_Exception_Code_1" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_2" ID="Address_2" TYPE="text" VALUE="C00000000C8C9D1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_2" ID="Count_2" TYPE="text" VALUE="0"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_2" ID="Device_Exception_2" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_2" ID="Device_Exception_Code_2" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_3" ID="Address_3" TYPE="text" VALUE="C00000000C8C9D1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_3" ID="Count_3" TYPE="text" VALUE="1"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_3" ID="Device_Exception_3" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_3" ID="Device_Exception_Code_3" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_4" ID="Address_4" TYPE="text" VALUE="2D0000000EE97D1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_4" ID="Count_4" TYPE="text" VALUE="1973018"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_4" ID="Device_Exception_4" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_4" ID="Device_Exception_Code_4" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_5" ID="Address_5" TYPE="text" VALUE="2D0000000EE97D1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_5" ID="Count_5" TYPE="text" VALUE="17260345"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_5" ID="Device_Exception_5" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_5" ID="Device_Exception_Code_5" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
</table><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<table name="Statistics" ID="Statistics">
```

I want to extract the values for each counter into a file or variable for further use.

I know that it is possible to use the owfs, but I wanted to have the flexibility to do it this way.

Comment: @DopeGhoti is correct when warning about the [first-class ticket to a descent into madness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not a regular language, so first be aware that attempting to parse it with regular expressions is a first-class ticket to a descent into madness.  That said, it looks like the HTML you're trying to chew on *should* lend itself to a fairly simple extraction.  The data you want to extract appear to be from these lines:

```
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_0" ID="Address_0" TYPE="text" VALUE="D90000000C8A9A1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_0" ID="Count_0" TYPE="text" VALUE="240155653"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_0" ID="Device_Exception_0" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_0" ID="Device_Exception_Code_0" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_1" ID="Address_1" TYPE="text" VALUE="D90000000C8A9A1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_1" ID="Count_1" TYPE="text" VALUE="48719610"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_1" ID="Device_Exception_1" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_1" ID="Device_Exception_Code_1" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_2" ID="Address_2" TYPE="text" VALUE="C00000000C8C9D1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_2" ID="Count_2" TYPE="text" VALUE="0"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_2" ID="Device_Exception_2" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_2" ID="Device_Exception_Code_2" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_3" ID="Address_3" TYPE="text" VALUE="C00000000C8C9D1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_3" ID="Count_3" TYPE="text" VALUE="1"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_3" ID="Device_Exception_3" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_3" ID="Device_Exception_Code_3" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_4" ID="Address_4" TYPE="text" VALUE="2D0000000EE97D1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_4" ID="Count_4" TYPE="text" VALUE="1973018"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_4" ID="Device_Exception_4" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_4" ID="Device_Exception_Code_4" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
<tr><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Address_5" ID="Address_5" TYPE="text" VALUE="2D0000000EE97D1D"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Count_5" ID="Count_5" TYPE="text" VALUE="17260345"></td><td colspan=1><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_5" ID="Device_Exception_5" TYPE="text" VALUE="OK"></td><INPUT CLASS="HA7Value" NAME="Device_Exception_Code_5" ID="Device_Exception_Code_5" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="0"></tr>
```

So, we can probably `sed` this:

```
$ sed -n '/HA7Value.*Address_/{ s/VALUE="/%%%/;s/^.*%%%//; s/".*//; p; }' input.html
D90000000C8A9A1D
D90000000C8A9A1D
C00000000C8C9D1D
C00000000C8C9D1D
2D0000000EE97D1D
2D0000000EE97D1D
```

To expound upon this:

```
/HA7Value.*Address_/ # Only run on lines that match this expression
{                    # Begin code block
  s/VALUE="/%%%/     # Replace (only) the first 'VALUE="' with a special marker
  s/^.*%%%//         # Delete everything up to that marker
  s/".*//            # Delete from the first '"' to the end of the line
  p                  # Print what's left
}                    # End code block
```